# I am unable to pass inputs from object array to java method

Tags: java, arrays, object, input, methods

I am making a java program to calculate area and perimeter of triangle and square where I need to create an object of both triangle and square classes and take inputs from them. I have written some code for it but it is not taking the inputs as arguments. I don't understand what might be the problem. Please help

geometricFigure.java - This is interface

```
public interface GeometricFigure {
    public void area(double sideOne, double sideTwo, double sideThree);
    public void perimeter(double sideOne, double sideTwo, double sideThree);
    public void print();
```

}

trisqu.java - This is the file with main function

```
public class trisqu{
public static void main(String[] args) {
double sideOne, sideTwo , sideThree;
 //Triangle tr = new GeometricFigure();
Triangle[] tr = new Triangle[3];
tr[0] = new Triangle(4,9,12);
tr[1] = new Triangle(9,16,25);
tr[2] = new Triangle(8,12,14);
for (int i=0;i<tr.length;i++){
    System.out.println("Triangle Object :"+(i+1)+" ");
    tr[i].area(sideOne, sideTwo, sideThree);
    tr[i].perimeter(sideOne, sideTwo, sideThree);
    tr[i].print();
    }



//Square sq = new GeometricFigure();
Square[] sq = new Square[3];
sq[0] = new Square(8);
sq[1] = new Square(32);
sq[2] = new Square(16);
for (int i=0;i<sq.length;i++){
    System.out.println("Square Object : "+(i+1)+ " ");
    sq[i].area(sideOne, sideTwo, sideThree);
    sq[i].perimeter(sideOne, sideTwo, sideThree);
    sq[i].print();
    }
  }
}
```

square.java - This is the file of square

```
public class Square implements GeometricFigure{
private double SqArea, SqPerimeter, side;
Square(double side){}


@Override
public void area(double sideOne, double sideTwo, double sideThree) {
    SqArea  = sideOne*sideOne;
    
}

@Override
public void perimeter(double sideOne,double sideTwo,double sideThree) {
    SqPerimeter  = sideOne*4;   
}

@Override
public void print(){
System.out.print("Area = "+SqArea+" Perimeter = "+SqPerimeter);
System.out.println("\n");
}
}
```

triangle.java- This is the file of the trianlge`

```
import java.lang.Math;


public class Triangle implements GeometricFigure{
private double sideOne, sideTwo, sideThree,TriArea,TriPerimeter;
public Triangle(double sideOne, double sideTwo, double sideThree){
    
}
double halfp = (sideOne + sideTwo + sideThree)/2;
@Override
public void area(double sideOne, double sideTwo, double sideThree){
    TriArea = Math.sqrt(halfp*(halfp - sideOne)*(halfp - sideTwo)*(halfp - sideThree));
}

@Override
public void perimeter(double sideOne, double sideTwo, double sideThree){
    TriPerimeter = sideOne + sideTwo + sideThree;
}

@Override
public void print(){
System.out.print("Area = "+TriArea+" Perimeter = "+TriPerimeter);
System.out.println("\n");
}

}
```

Please help, I am novice in java or any language for that matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multuple things to consider.

First, I belive you are using interfaces in the wrong way, in my opinion they should describe behavior (so abstract class here is a bit more preferable imho), and since the classes that implement the interface already have the values of the object you don't need to pass them.

Second, you are passing parameters to constructor but not assigning them to your class properties, which is a problem.

Third, when you pass `sideOne, sideTwo , sideThree` parameters in main, they are not initalized yet, however the most important part is that you don't need to pass them at all.

So all in all I would recommend you something like this:

```
public interface GeometricFigure {
    public double getArea();
    public double getPerimeter();
    public void print();
}
```

Next the classes that implement it should be as following:

```
public class Square implements GeometricFigure {
    private double side; // note that I have removed the area and perimeter variables

    Square(double side) {
        this.side = side;
    }

    @Override
    public double getArea() {
        return side * side;
    }

    @Override
    public double getPerimeter() {
        return side * 4;
    }

    @Override
    public void print() {
        System.out.print("Area = " + getArea() + " Perimeter = " + getPerimeter());
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
}
```

Note that the structure of the class has changed. It was done so that we wouldn't need to update the `area` and `perimeter` properties whenever the side is changed (if such a thing is possible).

I believe you can do the triangle thing yourself.

Now the main part:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Triangle[] tr = new Triangle[3];
        tr[0] = new Triangle(4,9,12);
        tr[1] = new Triangle(9,16,25);
        tr[2] = new Triangle(8,12,14);
        for (int i=0;i<tr.length;i++){
            System.out.println("Triangle Object :"+(i+1)+" ");
            tr[i].print();
        }

        Square[] sq = new Square[3];
        sq[0] = new Square(8);
        sq[1] = new Square(32);
        sq[2] = new Square(16);
        for (int i=0;i<sq.length;i++){
            System.out.println("Square Object : "+(i+1)+ " ");
            sq[i].print();
        }
    }
```

However if we wish to go a bit further, there is actually no need for the `print()` method in the `GeometricFigure`. The better approach for the simple tasks would be overriding `toString()` method:

```
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Area = " + getArea() + " Perimeter = " + getPerimeter();
    }
```

And then in the main simply doing the following:

```
   for (int i=0;i<sq.length;i++){
       System.out.println("Square Object : "+(i+1)+ " \n" + sq[i]);
   }
```

Comment: @MayankSharma you are welcome sir, if the answer satisfies you please mark it as a selected answer